# "How to print list data on a specific time delay list ?"

Tags: python

I want to print list data on the specific delays which are on another list. I Want to loop this process for a specific time, but I'm unable to implement it in a thread.

```
from time import sleep
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
Start_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
Str_time = Start_Time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
End_Time = '11:15:00'


class sampleTest:

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        list1 = ["Hello", "Hi", "Ola"]
        list2 = [5, 10, 7]
        # print(f"{data} delay {delay} & time is {t} ")
        # sleep(delay)
        i = 0
        while i < len(list1):
            t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print(f"{list1[i]} delay {list2[i]} & time is {t} ")
            sleep(list2[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            print("All Data is printed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = sampleTest
    while Str_time < End_Time:
        obj.test()
        Str_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    else:
        print("Time Is done")
```

Expected output: On first, loop it should print all list data but in the second loop, it should run as per the delay.

```
1st time: Hello, Hi, Ola
after that
 1. Every 5 seconds it should print Hello 
 2. Every 10 seconds it should print Hi  
 3. Every 7seconds it should print Ola
```

Actual Output: List of data is getting printed as per the delay.

```
Hello delay 5 & time is 11:41:45 
Hi delay 10 & time is 11:41:50 
Ola delay 3 & time is 11:42:00 
All Data is printed
Hello delay 5 & time is 11:42:03 
Hi delay 10 & time is 11:42:08 
Ola delay 3 & time is 11:42:18
```

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you are triggering delays on each print instead of printing at the appropriate times.

Comment: Yes, I want to print the data on the appropriate time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try comparing the current time with the start time, for example:

```
time.sleep(1);
diff = int(time.time() - start_time)
if (diff % wait_time == 0):
    print(text_to_print)
```

Here is the full code implementing this:

```
from time import sleep
import time
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
Start_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
Str_time = Start_Time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
End_Time = '11:15:00'
starttime=time.time()
diff = 0

class sampleTest:
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        list1 = ["Hello", "Hi", "Ola"]
        list2 = [5, 10, 7]

        for i in range(len(list1)):
          if (diff % list2[i] == 0):
            t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print(f"{list1[i]} delay {list2[i]} & time is {t} ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = sampleTest
    while Str_time < End_Time:
        obj.test()
        time.sleep(1);
        diff = int(time.time() - starttime)
        Str_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    else:
        print("Time Is done")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't apply the if-else condition, because both lists are dynamic.

Comment: The delay is not going to be the same always.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with your desired output, I believe threads are the best option, which means:

```
from time import sleep
import datetime
import threading

now = datetime.datetime.now()
Start_Time = datetime.datetime.now()
Str_time = Start_Time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
End_Time = '11:15:00'

class sampleTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run = True
        print ("1st time: Hello, Hi, Ola")
        print ("Now: " +  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

    def test(self, i):
        list1 = ["Hello", "Hi", "Ola"]
        list2 = [5, 10, 7]
        while self.run:
            sleep(list2[i])
            t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print(f"{list1[i]} delay {list2[i]} & time is {t}")

    def stop(self):
        self.run = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = sampleTest()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=obj.test,args=(0,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=obj.test,args=(1,))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=obj.test,args=(2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    while Str_time < End_Time:
        Str_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    else:
        obj.stop()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        t3.join()
        print("All data is printed")
        print("Time Is done")
```